# Preinititalising Neural Networks using Least Squares solution

Tags: neural-networks, least-squares

I am attempting to train a neural network, to approximate an unknown function.

The function domain and range is real valued vectors with 300 elements: all of which are between -1 and 1 (exclusive). The true function is many to one -- definitely not bijective, definitely not linear, though that does not mean the approximation couldn't be. A study has recently shown a related function can be approximated (to a degree that was good enough to be published) using the identity mapping.

I am attempting to approximate the function with a neural network:

$$x\mapsto tanh(Wx+b)$$
Which may not be powerful enough to model the function

This was fitting very slowly (using LBFGS),
I thought I might test how a simple linear approximation would fit,
trained to a least squares solution, so I took my training data ($x_{train}$, $y_{train}$), and solved for $$y_{train}=W_p \: x_{train}$$ via $W_p = y_{train}\:pinv(x_{train})$.
This came out with a tolerable fit -- mean squared error of about 50. (Not too bad, briefly trained neural networks were giving about 250).

I noticed that $W_p\approxeq tanh(W_p)$, and thought I might try initialising the neural network with $W=W_p$, and initialising the bias ($b$) with small random values from $\mathcal{N}(0,0.01)$. 
This has a initial performance of mean squared error 60ish, and has rapidly trained towards having one of 50ish, like the linear model. It seems to have significantly slowed down since then. I thought perhaps all it has done is train the bais down to zero and is suck in a local minima, but on terminating it and inspecting the bias, it seems this is not the case.

- **Is this a common way to initialise neural networks weights, when approximating a function?**
- **Is it intrinsically flawed -- will it almost certainly be stuck in a local minima that no better than the linear case?**

This method reminds me of [MSDAs,](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fpdf%2F1206.4683&ei=emh1VeScBIP88QX0lYC4DQ&usg=AFQjCNHOEjDLN1uLc19KAvVcbmuVNE04aQ&sig2=AM4UCeV8gUC783ypjuW05Q&bvm=bv.95039771,d.dGc) and of [DSNs](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/219986/ICASSP_2014.pdf).